Configure data column types in AirByte MySQL Connector
I built a custom source connector which calls HTTP APIs and syncs data to MySQL destination. The issue is that all columns in a target table created by AirByte MySQL connector are of text type. But I need VARCHAR - I don't want text column type. In AirByte documentation it's not really specified how to change column types for a destination. Is it possible at all?
This question is about AirByte MySQL connector configuration and not about how to change database column type manually.
